Pinia and Vue 3 using reactive arrays to store fixed amount of strings
Omitted import statements
Pinia store: inputData.ts
interface State {
    userInputValues: [
        string, string, string, string,
        string, string, string, string,
        string, string, string, string,
        string, string, string, string,
    ]
}


export const useInputDataStore = defineStore("inputData", {
    state: (): State => {
        return {
            userInputValues: [
                "", "", "", "",
                "", "", "", "",
                "", "", "", "",
                "", "", "", "",
            ]
        }
    }
})

I know there should be 16 strings in the array, so I defined an interface
I have a component here:
<script setup lang="ts">

const store = useInputDataStore();
const { userInputValues } = storeToRefs(store);


const props = defineProps<{
    inputId: number
}>();

// userInputValues is a Ref<[string, string, string...]>
// But how do I achieve it where I each string is a ref
// or userInputValues as Ref<[Ref<string>, Ref<string>, Ref<string>...]

// So here, inputBoxModel is a string not a Ref<string>
const inputBoxModel = userInputValues.value[inputId]

</script>

<template>
    <input v-model="inputBoxModel" />
</template>

What I'm trying to do
I want to have an array of 16 Ref<string>
But...
When I access the array, whats returned is a string, not a Ref<string>
So how can I make it reactive?

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Does this help?

@tao Apologies for my lack of clarity but yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so very much. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

I would define a fixed size array type as:
type FixedSizeArray<N extends number, T> = {
  length: N
} & ReadonlyArray<T>

which would make the store look like:
interface State {
  form: FixedSizeArray<16, string>
}

export const useFormStore = defineStore('form', {
  state: (): State => ({
    form: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
  })
})

And then you can import form in any component and use it like you would any other store state property.
Working example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sixteen-form-fnmjwg
Note: in the example I thought TS was smart enough to figure out that
Array.from({ length: 16 }).map(() => '') satisfies FixedSizeArray<16, string> but it gives the following error 1:
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'FixedSizeArray<16, string>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '{ length: 16; }'.
    Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '16'.ts(2322)

For now, the only options are:
a) a type assertion
form: <FixedSizeArray<16, string>>Array.from({ length: 16 }).map(() => '')

b) repetition:
form: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

c) moving the type assertion into a function
As for your issues with reactivity, the question isn't clear enough. See App.vue for implementation details in the above example.

1 - I've asked it as a separate question

This may be a side effect because actually the boundary between ref in another ref is not clear. I recommend creating composible to clarify this
function useInputValue(index: number) {
  const store = useInputDataStore()
  return computed<string>({
    get: () => store.userInputValues[ index ],
    set: val => store.userInputValues[ index ] = val
  })
}

and use
const inputBoxModel = useInputValue(props.inputId)

